# ec2 roles vs ec2 roles with temporary keys for s3 access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

So I have a standard Rails app running on ec2 that needs access to s3. I am currently doing it with long-term access keys, but rotating keys is a pain, and I would like to move away from this. It seems I have two alternative options:

One, tagging the ec2 instance with a role with proper permissions to access the s3 bucket. This seems easy to setup, yet not having any access keys seems like a bit of a security threat. If someone is able to access a server, it would be very difficult to stop access to s3. [Example](http://parthicloud.com/how-to-access-s3-bucket-from-application-on-amazon-ec2-without-access-credentials/)

Two, I can 'Assume the role' using the ruby SDK and STS classes to get temporary access keys from the role, and use them in the rails application. I am pretty confused how to set this up, but could probably figure it out. It seems like a very secure method, however, as even if someone gets access to your server, the temporary access keys make it considerably harder to access your s3 data over the long term.  [General methodology of this setup.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html)

I guess my main question is which should I go with? Which is the industry standard nowadays? Does anyone have experience setting up STS?

Sincere thanks for the help and any further understanding on this issue!

Answer (score 0):

All of the methods in your question require AWS Access Keys. These keys may not be obvious but they are there. There is not much that you can do to stop someone once they have access inside the EC2 instance other than terminating the instance. (There are other options, but that is for forensics)

You are currently storing long term keys on your instance. This is strongly NOT recommended. The recommended "best practices" method is to use IAM Roles and assign a role with only required permissions. The AWS SDKs will get the credentials from the instance's metadata.

You are giving some thought to using STS. However, you need credentials to call STS to obtain temporary credentials. STS is an excellent service, but is designed to for handing out short term temporary credentials to others - such as the case where your web server is creating credentials via STS to hand to your users for limited case use such as accessing files on S3 or sending an email, etc. The fault in your thinking about STS is that once the bad guy has access to your server, he will just steal the keys that you call STS with, thereby defeating the need to call STS.

In summary, follow best practices for securing your server such as NACLs, security groups, least privilege, minimum installed software, etc. Then use IAM Roles and assign the minimum privileges to your EC2 instance. Don't forget the value of always backing up your data to a location that your access keys CANNOT access.

Comment: Thanks so much, John. Really appreciate it. I will go with ec2 role tagging. I guess I thought the plethora of documentation for STS meant it was applicable to this common s3 use case.

Comment: I like to think thru the damage that leaked access keys can cause. For example, deleting all my data in the S3 bucket. Always have a copy of the bucket that the keys cannot access. Next example, uploading "bad" files to my s3 bucket, Don't allow S3 PutObject permission. Accessing privileged files. Encrypt everything. Think thru short and long term damage and then install detection, prevention and backup strategies.